# Symfony 2.8 to 3.4: Simple array of entity IDs not saving

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm updating an app from Symfony 2.8 to 3.4.

I used to store a collection of entities sending an AJAX request (not using Twig's form_xxx helpers)

This is a typical payload:

```
my_healthbundle_anamnesistype[habits][]: 5
my_healthbundle_anamnesistype[diseases][]: 9
my_healthbundle_anamnesistype[diseases][]: 10
```

These had no special treatment on the AnamnesisType form builder, no ChoiceType or EntityType, whatsoever, just:

```
$builder->add('habits')
        ->add('allergies')
        ->add('interventions')
        ->add('diseases')
```

All of these entities are super simple, just an ID and a Name field.

Each one of these is mapped in the Anamnesis entity as such:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Habits")
*/
protected $habits;
```

The controller code was:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new AnamnesisType(), $entity);
$request = $this->getRequest();
$editForm->bind($request);
if ($editForm->isValid()) {
   /// WIN!
```

All of this worked like a charm in 2.8. As you can see this was super simple and straight forward. The form builder has no reference to any entity classes, choice type, entity types, nothing. By sending the mentioned payload and calling `->bind()` all the "habits" inside an "Anamnesis" were replaced.

After updating the deprecated stuff and following all recommendations (`getRequest()` became a call to `request_stack`, `bind()` became `handleRequest()`, create form changed from "`new AnamnesisType`" to "`AnamnesisType::class`", etc), the `isValid()` method is returning false, and I'm getting an empty string when calling `$editForm->getErrors(true, false)`

Am I missing a step here? Did the way collections from a Request are saved into a form as entites changed? Any help is appreciated, this is the last blocker to finally upgrade to 3.4 and then 4.0.

Comment: It would be clearer to put the code as it is now. The most important is to know where the issue comes from, and it's in the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `$editForm->isSubmitted()` call inside the if condition. I would expect your updated code to look something like this:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new AnamnesisType(), $entity);
$request = $this->getRequest();

$editForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Calling isValid without isSubmitted is deprecated, but it still works with Symfony < 4.0

Comment: Thanks! noted, but I'm using 3.4 and `$editForm->isValid()` is `false`, so even with `isSubmitted` it will never enter the if condition.

I just tried switching from `handleRequest($request)` to `submit($request)`, by using `submit` I get at least an error message:  "ERROR: This value is not valid". But I still don't know what the "error" is.

Comment: Do you use the WebProfiler-Toolbar? If so you can see why the validation fails, e.g. by going to `http://localhost:8000/_profiler` (if you use the internal webserver defaults), then going to the validation tab. Any messages in the logs?